# Is there a way to fetch data before react functional component render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm quite new to react and I created a functional component with an error.

**What i want to achieve:**
I need to get data from the reducer and use it in the functional return.
The problem is that the component rendered before the data loaded.


**My code:**

```js
function ItemDetail() {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const [{items}, dispatch] = useStateValue(); // useStateValue = datalayer from reducer
    const [item, setEvent] = useState({});
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const filteredItem = items.find(item=> item.id == id);
        setEvent(filteredItem);
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="eventDetail">
            // more HTML
        </div>
    )
    
}

export default ItemDetail
```

**What I tried:**
I tried to use a class component but i didn't got it working.

**The error:**
item.data() is not a function (i'm 100% sure its because the data is not loaded in the return)

Comment: you could try swr https://swr.vercel.app/

Comment: Ciao, where is item.data()? In return ?

Comment: `return !item ? null : <OtherStuff />`

Comment: There is no `item.data` in your code snippet. Please include a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example.